# Nhibernate Not detecting changes to parent when child collection updates

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How do you set in nhibernate so that when calling session.Save(), it will detect changes to its collections.

Wanted to update the parent record when a child collection changes (either insert, update, or delete).

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to update the parent? Is it about optimistic locking? You don't need to call update if the entities are attached. Do you have detached entities?

Comment: The parent is the main record. e.g. if you update the Grade of one subject, the whole student records updated date should also update. My problem is that there is an automatic way that nhibernate saves only if there are changes to its properties, but I also want to check if its collections have updates

Answer (score 0):

You can set Nhibernate to save child collection changes when you save the parent by setting cascade attribute on the collection definition so your collection mapping will look something like this:

```
<bag name="Children" table="tblChildren" inverse ="true" cascade="all-delete orphan" lazy="true">
  <key column="ChildId"/>
  <one-to-many class="XXXX.Child, XXX"/>
</bag>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent change date is something that needs to be handled by your business logic. If you set it explicitly, NH will save it. If the change date is set in an NHibernate event or interceptor, you're lost, because NH doesn't have a reason to update the parent.

You should actually have a kind of service which handles parent changes. Children are not changed directly without at least letting this service know about it. This service sets the parent's change date explicitly. It's part of the business logic.

Comment: Yeah, I was just expecting that the layer which detects if an entity has changes, could also detect if the entities child collection has changes. Inserting additional logic to that layer should be enough but I'm not sure if that is exposed somewhere in NH